# Probability to guess a number

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Les's have the next situation:

There is a system who asks for certification.

For that , the system sends you a seed of 16 bits , and you need to response with a  result of 24 bit.
Each time, the seed is different and uniformly.

What is the probability to keep wrong in the guess for N times, with the next algorithm:

Each time you get the seed, randomise a uniformly 24 bit value and hope for good.

What is the probability to not succeed after 100000000 (N) trials.

Is it $(1-\frac{1}{2^{24}})^N$ or $(1-\frac{1}{2^{40}})^N$ ?

For your information, a success is to give the correct response (nevertheless what is the seed)

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: What do *YOU* think is the answer? What is your rational for each of those?  What's your pobability of guessing wrong $1$ time?  If you guess 24 bits why would the 16 bits make your guess less likely.

Comment: That is what I am asking. The remaining 16 bit does not affect my wrong guess probability? So , the wrong probability remains in with the first answer (24 in the exponent)? Thanks

Comment: If I understand your question correctly (which I not sure I do) then are $2^{24}$ possible answers but only one is right.  I suppose this can be complicated in that there are only $2^{16}$ possible right answers and $2^{24} -2^{16}$ of the possible answers will never be the right ones.  But the guesser has *no* way of knowing which ones they will be.

Comment: Thought experiment.  A machine randomly picks an integer $1$ to $5$ and a dog randomly picks an integer $1$ to $8$.  What is prob the dog guesses the same number.  Method 1: There is $1$ right answer and $8$ possible guesses. $\frac 18$. Method 2: There is a $\frac 58$ probality the dog guesses in the range. And if so a $\frac 15$ prob of guessing right.  There is a $\frac 38$ prob of the dog guessing in the wrong range. And if s a $0$ prob of guessing right.  So prob of guessing right is $\frac 58*\frac 15 + \frac 38*0=\frac 18$.  Either method is okay.

Comment: Yes. It is right. The seed does not affect my correct guess probability. To be correct with a specific pairs of (key ,seed) is 2^40 , but there are 2^16 options , so it is 2^24